# iOS, Cocoa, AppiRater - How to localized Cancel Button for SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring, appirater

How can I localize the "Cancel" button in the AppiRater view controller that is popped over?

I was looking in the AppiRater code... it makes us of the `SKStoreProductViewController` like this:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
```

Basically I want to something like this:

```
[storeViewcontroller.navigationBar.cancelButton setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appirator? Rating SDK?

[Here is localized version of Appirator.](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)

Make sure you added all .lproj folder to your Xcode project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i have added it. Still in the simulator it is not showing, but on the device its fine ...

Comment: Perhaps your language setting in the simulator is different from your device?

Comment: no the simulator is set to german. also the app is showing german. but the appirator popover is completely in english. i don't know why. on the device everything is correctly in german... so no issues... thx

Comment: This is because appirator doesnot work in simulator. You can't rate/review an app via simulator.