# Loading a localized version of SKStoreProductViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, storekit

Inside my iOS application, I have a function to redirect to AppStore to load a particular AppId.

```
static NSInteger const appITunesItemIdentifier = 0000000000;

SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
storeProductViewController.delegate = self;

NSNumber *identifierNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:appITunesItemIdentifier];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:identifierNumber };

[storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters
                               completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (result)
                                       [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController
                                                                    animated:YES
                                                                  completion:nil];
                                   else NSLog(@"%s - %d # Error descriotion = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [error description]);
                               }];
```

This will load the related view accurately like in below image.

[image]

What I need is to localize the navigation bar button items to the device language.

In the picture, you can see the text in status bar is in Swedish. Is there a way that we can change the "Cancel" and "Store" texts to Swedish?

OR

Does that language depend on any settings that we have given in the AppStore account. I mean region, country or any other parameter?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121978/ios-cocoa-appirater-how-to-localized-cancel-button-for-skstoreproductviewcon

Comment: The app from which you are displaying this `SKStoreProductViewController`; is it localized to Swedish?

Comment: @DaveWeston in a way it is localized, but not with standard procedure. What I mean is, we don't keep text inside the application. We fetch text from a remote server depending on the user's system language (selected in the device) or user preference (selected inside the app). When it is comes to `SKStoreProductViewController` view, I haven't override any navigation bar items to, change it texts. But my device and our application language is already set to Swedish (Svenska)